# Eclipse: Native proxy setting goes missing, breaking network connectivity

Tags: eclipse, proxy

For no discernible reason, the native proxy provider (see pic) of my Eclipse (Photon 4.8) sometimes goes missing. This results in Eclipse no longer having internet access. I have not found a way to add this provider again except restarting Eclipse.

[image]

My main two questions are: Can I add this provider again once it goes missing? What could be the reason why it vanishes in the first place?

Comment: what is your operating system and how is it acquiring the proxy configuration?

Comment: Windows 7. Not sure about the Proxy config, it's done by company IT.

Comment: Complain to IT, seems they are changing host:port too often or their proxy is unstable. Ask them to provide an static host :p . Is that the only app loosing internet access?

Comment: I don't think it's IT changing the proxy. I've had the issue just a few minutes apart at times. Eclipse is the only problematic program.
I've already tried using a static host but then I can't resolve internal addresses anymore.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the [*Network Connections* dialog](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm), you should see a *Restore Defaults* button. For most cases, that should suffice.

[image]

Comment: That does not bring back the line for the native proxy and does not restore connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when using some photon versions. I had the same problem, but I downgrade version and everything was fine. There is a reporting bug in Click [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533455).

If this problem persists, report your case. Nothing can be done to fix the problem at runtime.

Comment: I've found that bug report but it is for Oxygen (4.7) and Java 9 and 10. I'm using Java 1.8.

Comment: Try to reinstall Eclipse and create a new workspace. I think this should help.

Comment: Normally, when we enable proxy on eclipse, we enable all types of proxies – HTTP, HTTPS, and SOCKS.
The issue is that if you add ‘SOCKS’ proxy entry, eclipse will ignore HTTP/HTTPS whereas normally you will always connect to an HTTP/S url.
So try solution is that remove ‘SOCKS’ proxy entry and keep only HTTP/HTTPS entry.